# How to install GUI on remote Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vnc, xrdp

I need to install GUI on a VPS Linux server. Service provider is Hetzner and Linux version is Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS I'm using MobaXterminal for X11 forwarding. And I'm using root credentials.

I have tried the following:

Gnome, KDE, xfce4, MATE desktop with port 22 and port 3389 They always show the same error:

> connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350 sesman connect ok sending
> login info to session manager, please wait... login failed for display
> 0

VNC server installation I followed the guide on https://vitux.com/ubuntu-vnc-server/ but it showed an error like this.

> vncserver@1.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
> vncserver@1.service: Failed with result 'timeout'. Failed to start
> Remote desktop service (VNC).

Please don't write URL links to similar answers to my problem. I've tried more than 20 advises on the internet. None of them worked for me.

Please can anyone provide me a step-by-step solution?

Comment: Usually GUIs are not installed on VPSes because they don't have the graphics power to support it. Does your service provider offer machines that are designed for RDC connections?

Comment: I only need the GUI to open up firefox, which I need. 
How much processing power is required for RDC connections?
I thought there would be a lightweight solution for this.

Comment: Okay, the actual task is to use pywhatsapp python script. But it relies on whatsapp web login, which requires a graphical user interface. (Because whatsapp login requires QR code recognition with mobile phone) 
It would be a relief, if I could circumvent this without installing gui on the server.

Comment: One option would be to sign in with a browser on your development machine, watch the network traffic that travels between your machine and the remote servers, then copy the bearer authentication token to the server. So long as the tokens do not need to cycle or expire very often, this may be a workable solution 

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but can I operate the browser without gui?

Comment: You wouldn't be using a browser on the remote server, but on your *local* machine. Don't try to over-complicate this 

Comment: I will post another question regarding this issue, so please try to clarify.

Comment: I left a comment on your other question too, but installing a GUI on a VPS could very well be prohibited by the VPS provider, regardless of whether it's technically doable.

Comment: Since a VPS is functioning like a dedicated server, you can install almost any software products you want.

Comment: You can run Firefox via X11. This does not require a GUI, but the performance is probably not so good...